# Trekking in Russia similar to Kungsleden

Tags: trekking, russia, solo-trekking

I've been walking the Kungsleden in the Sweden Lapland recently and I enjoyed it very much. I'd like to try again a similar trek but this time I'd love to go to either Kamchatka or South Siberia (near Baikal lake).

Is there a trek in one of those places which is similar to the Kungsleden? With similar I mean that the the path is well marked, it's possible to sleep in huts (even tho I'm also considering bring a tent this time) and it can be walked alone, without guides or tour.